# JavaScript Code in jSON Response (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm having a problem with a javasciprt code in a jSON response.

The response is:

```
$return['msg'] = '<a onClick = "delComment(comment_'.$number.', '.$number.', '.$comment_id.')" href="javascript:void()" style="float: right; padding-right: 5px;">'.SayLang::json('COMMENT_DELETE').'</a>';
```

delComment function:

```
function delComment(div_id, comment_number, comment_id) {
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (logged_in == null) var logged_in = false;
    if (admined == null) var admined = false;
    if (confirm('Biztosan törölni szeretnéd a hozzászólást?')) {
        $('#ajax-json-response').fadeOut('fast').html('');
        $('#ajax-loading-content').html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />').fadeIn('slow');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'json.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            timeout: 100000,
            data: { a: 'comment_delete', div_id: div_id, comment_number: comment_number, comment_id: comment_id },
            success: function(data) {
                $('#ajax-loading-content').fadeOut(1).html('');
                $('#ajax-json-response').html(data.message).fadeIn('slow');
                if (!data.error) {
                    $('input#number').val(data.newnumber);
                    $('#'+div_id).toggle('slow');
                    if (data.newnumber == 0) {
                        $('#no-comment').fadeIn('slow');
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('#ajax-loading-content').fadeOut(1).html('');
                //$('#ajax-json-response').html('Probléma történt! Kérlek próbáld újra később! (HTTP Error: '+errorThrown+' | Error Message: '+textStatus+')').fadeIn('slow');
                $('#ajax-json-response').html('Probléma történt! Kérlek próbáld újra később!').fadeIn('slow');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

}

After I click the link, Chrome Crashes and Mozilla doesn't do anything.

What's the problem, or what should I do?

Thanks in advance: Marcell

Comment: Not sure why you have `$(document).ready()` within a function that will only be called `onclick`.  The point of `$(document).ready()` is to ascertain whether the DOM is loaded yet, and for a link to be clicked - it must be.

Comment: The response is not valid json so far. Did you use json_encode() for output(assuming php)?

Comment: Can you give us the console error messages? Ctrl + Shift + J in Chrome

Comment: I don't get error. Just crashes the Chrome. But it (console) sometimes says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )" and I don't get error on the site, and it's working with unexpacted token, but only when I don't click the JS from jSON response.

Comment: after some minutes of waiting it shows only "error"

Comment: firebug says: "comment_3 is not defined" or "comment_1", etc...

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP variable is `$return['msg']` but you call `data.message` in javascript could that be it? Also you wrap your inner function with `$(document).ready(function() {` which is totally unnecessary, try removing that.

Comment: It's "message" in my PHP, I've only copied a bad row, and I've deleted the DOM ready row, but it's still not OK. Console only shows "error"

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found the problem.

It was invalid:

```
$return['message'] = '<a onClick = "delComment(-->comment_'.$number.'<--';
```

Thanks for help!